# Mysite.com/vasya

Tags: веб-программирование, php

Hello world!

Вот заходит ко мне на $site Vasya и регистрируется.
После чего он может получить доступ к своей личной странице по адресу 
http://$site/Vasya

Как такое реализуется? Могу я такой запрос роутить на index.php?user=Vasya?

Answer (score 2):

Вам поможет файл htaccess, он позволяет настраивать переадресацию.
Вот доступная статья по конфигурации - http://beget.ru/ua/art_htaccess